# Apple confused in product type - in app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I got rejected from Apple today,
They say

> We noticed that your in-app purchase product is set to an incorrect
>   product type.
>
> (Paid Plan) is set to Non-Consumable.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Since the service offered by your app requires the user to make an
>   advance payment to access the content or receive the service, please
>   use the non-renewable subscription in-app purchase product type.
>   Non-renewable subscription content must be made available to all iOS
>   devices owned by a single user, as indicated in guideline 3.1.2 of the
>   App Store Review Guidelines

But in my app, I just have a package to get full access(remove Ads, add some features) 
And the user just buy it **once**!

So that's why I use Non-Consumable.
why apple rejected it?

Comment: `Paid Plan` sounds like you would call a `subscription`. Maybe you should use some different name for it?

Comment: @user28434 So apple reject it for the name! Name like what can you suggest one?

Comment: Idk, maybe something like "Premium" or "Unlock all features", "Upgrade to pro edition" and add description that univocally describes what would happen when user pays for it.

Comment: Maybe this apple guide(*?*) will somehow help: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/freemium-business-model/

Comment: Great, thank you, should I upload new build? And re submitting it? Or just reply to Apple and describe the misunderstanding?

Comment: You should definitely rename and resubmit your IAP (separate review from the app). If your app doesn't have proper IAP description in UI somewhere you will have to add it and upload a new build. Replying to apply probably won't help with current review, but you can try to clarify if the problem is just in the name.